# Alarm clock time and date format using ReactJS (MUI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My code implemented so far is:

```
const date = new Date();
  const currentTime = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  const getDay = `${date.getDay()} ${date.getMonth()} ${date.getDate()}`;

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography>{currentTime}</Typography>
      <Typography>{getDay}</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
```

But I get

14:6:56

2 10 8

The below image is the format I was looking for.

[image: format]

Answer (score 1):

Check this doc. You have all the methods for dates https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

7:32 PM
Tue, November 8

```html
const App = () => {
  const now = new Date()
  const opt = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
  }
  const optt = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    weekday: 'short',
  }

  const clock = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', opt).format(now)
  const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', optt).format(now)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{clock}</div>
      <div>{date}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

paste this code and render App in react

Comment: Thank you! That's a really cool approach! Any idea how to remove the PM AM indicator and make it 19:32 rather than 7:32 PM?

Comment: add   hour12: false, to opt

Comment: const opt = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',                                                                                                 
    hour12: false,                                                                                                                         
  }